Getting "Target not found" after programming an STM32H755 using an external debugger
I used to program and debug using the USB port on my STM32H755 Nucleo-144.
After flashing the code with JTAG, I can't connect the board to my PC anymore; it says "No target found". Is there any way of recovering from this?

This can happen when you reprogram your JTAG pins. On a Nucleo board you have a reset button, you can try to press that and select connect under reset or something like that and maybe that works. Another workaround would be to use the boot pin to force the MCU to startup into the bootloader which doesn't reconfigure the JTAG pins. Or you just killed the MCU.
